# JQuery Mobile Latest 03 June 2011 Version - No back button

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

It's the 3rd June 2011 and I'm using JQuery Mobile's latest version.

My problem is that the back button has gone.

How can I get the back button to show up please?

UPDATE:

I've tried this but still not back button.

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" data-theme="a" data-iscroll="enable" data-add-back-btn="true">

    <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" data-backbtn="true">
        <h1>title here</h1>

        <a href="index.php" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left jqm-home">Home</a>
        <a href="view.php" data-icon="arrow-r" data-theme="a" data-iconpos="right">Events</a>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you look at the [jQuery mobile blog post in may](http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/05/20/jquery-mobile-team-update-%E2%80%93-week-of-may-16th/), the back button is now off by default.

To reenable the back button simply add `data-add-back-btn="true"` to the page container:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>First page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p><a href="#page2">page2</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Optional footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-add-back-btn="true">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Second Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">  
        <p><a href="#page1">page1</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Optional footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Example of the back button on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Bxa2U/4/)**

Comment: See updated answer and fiddle, the added data-* should add the back button assuming you navigated to another page.

Comment: Also, make sure you're including the latest version of jQuery. I was including 1.5.2 and it wasn't showing up. Upgrading to 1.6.1 (and using the `data-add-back-btn` attribute) did the trick.

Comment: Hoorah for backwards compatibility! Doco is pretty rubbish but here is the link anyway. Thanks Mark.  http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

Answer (score 7):

If you're still not seeing it and your markup is all correct, Mark's comment is helpful:

> assuming you navigated to another page

I wasn't seeing a back button on the page I was testing when adding the attribute:

```
data-add-back-btn="true"
```

It was because there was no browser history on that tab of my browser, thus no chance of a back button. If I navigated to the page I was testing from another page, then I would see the back button.

Answer (score 3):

As back button is now turned off by default, you need to turn it on before loading jQuery mobile (and after loading jQuery):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
      $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
 });    
</script>
```

Also, to prevent back button's sometimes popping up where it shouldn't be, put this:

```
data-add-back-btn="false"
```

to page containers on all pages where you don't want to see back button ever.

Answer (score 3):

include data-add-back-btn="true" in header div tag

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>First page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <p><a href="#page2">page2</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Optional footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true">
        <h1>Second Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">  
        <p><a href="#page1">page1</a></p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Optional footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a same problem though I have tried all steps above.
I also found issues and solutions.

Issues: Back button is on the left of header and there may be buttons in this position already.

Solution: Move buttons to the right of the header by adding class="ui-btn-right" to buttons

Answer (score 2):

Add this code

```
<script>
     $(document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
          $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
     });
</script>
```

**BEFORE** you define

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
```