# Cannot a Back button to nested list (Latest Version)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm having problems trying to get the back button to show in a nexted list. I can see that the same is happening to your demo's here:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/lists/lists-nested.html

You can see the problem here:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/lists/lists-nested.html&ui-page=Animals-8

or just click any list.

Here is my actually issue:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">';
<li data-icon="info">
<h3 class="ui-li-heading">Heading here</h3>
<p class="ui-li-desc">Author:&nbsp;<strong>some author</strong></p>
<p class="ui-li-desc">Description:&nbsp;<strong>some description</strong></p>

            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-add-back-btn="true">
                <li>sometthing here</li>
            </ul>

</li>
</ul>
```

Is this a bug or I'm I forgetting something?

Thanks

UPDATE: Another example:

```
<ul data-role='listview'>
            <li>
                <li><div>Some Text</div><p>ddd</p>
                    <ul data-role='listview'>

                        <li>
                            some text here
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

No back button. How do I make the back button appear?

Comment: Try the solution posted here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522106/jquery-mobile-nested-list-back-button-gone, it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

To reenable the back button simply add `data-add-back-btn="true"` to the page container:

Related: [JQuery Mobile Latest 03 June 2011 Version - No back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221527/jquery-mobile-latest-03-june-2011-version-no-back-button)

You are using the tests and not the demo, so I guess this would be the latest (or close to) build.

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/#/test/docs/lists/lists-nested.html
- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/lists/index.html

UPDATE:

- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html

> **Adding Back buttons**
>
> jQuery Mobile has a feature to automatically
>   create and append "back" buttons to any header, though it is disabled
>   by default. This is primarily useful in chromeless installed
>   applications, such as those running in a native app web view. The
>   framework automatically generates a "back" button on a header when the
>   page plugin's addBackBtn option is true. This can also be set via
>   markup if the page div has a data-add-back-btn="true" attribute.
>
> If you use the attribute data-rel="back" on an anchor, any clicks on
>   that anchor will mimic the back button, going back one history entry
>   and ignoring the anchor's default href. This is particularly useful
>   when linking back to a named page, such as a link that says "home", or
>   when generating "back" buttons with JavaScript, such as a button to
>   close a dialog. When using this feature in your source markup, be sure
>   to provide a meaningful href that actually points to the URL of the
>   referring page (this will allow the feature to work for users in
>   C-Grade browsers. Also, please keep in mind that if you just want a
>   reverse transition without actually going back in history, you should
>   use the data-direction="reverse" attribute instead.

Maybe try:

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.addBackBtn = true;
});
```

Comment: Where do we add it to so it appears on the automatically generated pages, though? The question is about the nested lists, and for lower level ul/ol's the page is created automatically by the framework. Putting  data-add-back-btn="true" on the top-level list, or the li, or the actual ul - doesn't help, the back button does not appear.

Comment: I have update my answer. Note that this could change as jQM is still in beta

Comment: The solution described here helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522106/jquery-mobile-nested-list-back-button-gone

Comment: Had the same issue, check my answer here for a complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522106/jquery-mobile-nested-list-back-button-gone/7438750#7438750